# App not seeing my Virtual Environment although it is active

Tags: python, linux, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I have a Virtual Environment active where I have added all pip modules requied for a desired app to run.

However, when I try and run it I get Import errors where the path specified does not relate to the virtual environment  - even though it has been set active. These import errors are justified as the pip modules it refers to do not exist on that path, they only exist in my virtual environment python path.

When I enter `$PATH` into the terminal the result is;

```
bash: /home/default_user/MY_VE/bin:/home/default_user/.pythonbrew/bin:/home/default_user/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.5/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

Does this indicate a problem or do I need to do something like mve my app to another directory for it to check the PATH which relates to the virtual environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you activate the environnement with source .../bin/activate ? Check this : http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: how you activate your `VN` ? and what modules you have been imported ?

Comment: so i activated it from my home directory by doing source MY_VE/bin/activate